# How to interact with remote machine outside of a session?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-remoting

I'd like to install software on some of my domain computers silently. Since these software packages don't come in the form of an MSI, I thought I'll try to do it using Powershell.

In a first step, I set up Powershell remoting. The following command works:

```
PS $ Test-WSMan -ComputerName rmtComputer

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

The software packages to be installed are on network shares. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to start these install files directly. As Kevin Marquette explains in [his article on Powershell](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-22-Powershell-installing-remote-software/), this is due to some double hop credential problem. The solution is to first copy the setup file from the share to a local folder, then start the setup.

In the same article, he shows 2 ways of doing that. The first way looks as follows:

```
Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "\\$computername\c$\windows\temp\installer.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
    c:\windows\temp\installer.exe /silent
}
```

Neither of these 2 commands works for me. Running the `copy-item` command returns `The network path was not found`. I can confirm that both the computer as well as the user have read access to the respective share.

Running the `invoke-command` command doesn't return any errors but nothing happens on the computer in question.

Marquette goes on to describe another way of doing the same, using a Remote Session:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName
Copy-Item -Path $file -ToSession $session -Destination 'c:\windows\temp\installer.exe'

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    c:\windows\temp\installer.exe /silent
}
Remove-PSSession $session
```

This, on the other hand, works perfectly. Any hint you can give me as to why this works but the other way doesn't?

Comment: There is a number of reasons why `Copy-Item` could fail. For instance, administrative shares could be disabled on the remote host, or a firewall could be blocking SMB connections. `Invoke-Command` probably doesn't do anything b/c the executable you're trying to invoke isn't there (although I would expect a "command not found" type error in that case). But if the connection failed you should definitely be seeing an error. The second code snippet probably works b/c the file isn't transferred via SMB, but WinRM (which uses a different port). More information is required for a definitive answer.

Comment: If the goal is to install software on remote computers within an `AD Domain`, take a look a [Windows PowerShell Desired State Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview/overview)

Comment: Fix the first thing first. Why isn't the copy item working? Try adding the '-verbose' switch to the copy-Item command and read the output to find out how it;s translating your path variables and which path (source or destination) is causing the error.